# iPhone SDK zoomin/zoomout multiple uiimageviews

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am able to apply panzoom effect to one uiimageview using uiscrollview. How can I apply panzoom effect to multiple uiimageviews in a single scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/) which explains how to zoom, rotate & move multiple image.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this can solve your problem, but if you can make a separate class (inheriting UIView) which displays single image. That class should be able to handle zooming functionality. and then in your class creates multiple objects of this class.
I hope this will solve your problem.

Of course, memory utilization could be the issue if not properly handled.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But I have to zoom all images in the current view simultaneously. Any way to achieve this without using uiscrollview?